# Prevent handle from disappearing when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery and jQuery ui draggable. I have a handle that appears on hover that's used to drag a div around. It works well except when it's dragged very fast. The hover seems to be deactivated and the handle disappears in the middle of the drag. How can I prevent this form happening?

Here is a jsfiddle of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/1/

```
    $(function() {
        $("#handle").draggable({handle: "dragHandle"}).hover(function(){
             $(this).toggleClass("outline");
        });          
    });
```

BTW, I'm using Safari.

---

CSS Only Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/42/

Comment: A bit late but I also contributed with an answer :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the `containment` option?

```
$(function() {
    $("#handle").draggable({
        handle: "dragHandle",
        containment: "parent"
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/27/).

=== UPDATE ===

On *drag* `start` set a class and remove it on *drag* `stop`:

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#handle").draggable({
        handle: "dragHandle",
        containment: "parent",
        start: function() {
            $('.dragHandle').addClass('test');
        },
        stop: function() {
            $('.dragHandle').removeClass('test');
        }

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.handle:hover .dragHandle, .test {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color: #842899;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-25px;
    cursor: move;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also see [my updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/41/).

Comment: Still disappears on fast mouse moves.

Comment: the update is solid and it much more reliable than hover. Thanks, bro.

Comment: Using the same concept of your solution I came up with another using CSS only. jQuery UI draggable adds a class of "ui-draggable-dragging" to the parent container when dragging. I'm then able to do ".ui-draggable-dragging .dragHandle" and make the visibility dependent on the class being there vs using additional JS. Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/42/

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/39/

```
$(function()
{
    var isMouseDown = false;

    $("#handle").draggable(
    {
        handle: "dragHandle"
    });

    $("#handle").mousedown( function()
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
        $(this).addClass("outline");
    });

    $("#handle").mouseup( function()
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
    });

    $("#handle").hover( function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("outline");
    },
    function()
    {
        if ( isMouseDown == false )
        {
            $(this).removeClass("outline");
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: this definitely works...but man, it's so much js to handle such a small thing (not complaining about your work specifically).

Answer (score 0):

I used a 'flag' to capture the mousedown event, and setted by default the `.dragHandle` to be CSS: `display:none;`

```
var holded = false;
$('.handle').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
   (e.type==='mouseleave' && holded===false) ? $('.dragHandle').hide() :  $('.dragHandle').show() ;
}).on('mousedown mouseup',function(e){
    e.type==='mousedown' ? holded=true: holded=false;
});

$(".handle").draggable({handle: "dragHandle"});
```

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m7KEX/)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem with quick mouse moves is that is so fast that it actually de-hovers before the div even gets a chance to be rendered under the mouse cursor. So, in CSS replace:

```
 .outline .dragHandle {
```

with:

```
 .outline .dragHandle, .dragHandle:active {
```

This way when the handle is kept clicked, it won't disappear.

Comment: that's clever. Unfortunately, it still looks like it's disappearing. http://jsfiddle.net/JdtsV/40/

Comment: Yes, I though it might not work cross-browser. It works on Opera.